# Get Initials From Full Names In PHP Array

Tags: php, explode, implode

I would like to take a list of names (from Wordpress) and get the initials and separate them by '/'.  In most cases, there will be 2 or more names.  In some cases there will be just 1 name.

**For example:**

John Doe
Jane Adams
Michael McDonald

**should output:**
JD/JA/MD

Here is what I have tried so far in my attempt to figure it out.

```
foreach ( $result as $user )
{
   $user_id = $user->user_id1;
   $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
   $name[] = $user->display_name;
}
$comma_names =  implode('/', $name);

$words = explode("/", $comma_names);
    $initials = ""; 
    foreach ($words as $w) {
        $initials .= $w[0];
        
    }

 echo $initials;
```

Obviously, this only outputs the first letter of each name.  Do I need to use an additional explode in my loop?

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: https://chrisblackwell.me/generate-perfect-initials-using-php/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `$words` is an array of names (it's not 100% clear from your code), you can use `preg_match_all` to find the first characters in each name, then implode those values to get the initials string, and then implode all those results again to get your desired string. For example:

```
$words = array(
    'John Doe',
    'Jane Adams',
    'Michael McDonald',
    'Jim'
    );
    
$initials = implode('/', array_map(function ($name) { 
    preg_match_all('/\b\w/', $name, $matches);
    return implode('', $matches[0]);
}, $words));
echo $initials;
```

Output:

```
JD/JA/MM/J
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HGX0j)

If there's guaranteed to only be one space between names, you can simplify that code to just replace any character in the name string that is preceded by a word character with nothing:

```
$initials = implode('/', array_map(function ($name) { 
    return preg_replace('/(?<=\w)./', '', $name);
}, $words));
```

The output will be the same for the sample data. [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/cUgfa)